# jQuery snap elements inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I added JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/c62rsff3/**

I am trying to make 2 elements snap to each other with this code:

```
$('.draggable-elements').draggable({ snap: true });
```

I also have a container with a width and a height of 400px. And I can't find a way for the elements not to get outside my container while dragging them.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="draggable-elements"></div>
      <div class="draggable-elements"></div>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to play with the elements only inside the container I have created, more like a canvas would work.

Any ideas?

Comment: No dots in class attributes : `class="draggable-elements"`

Comment: Added a JSFiddle as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the property 'containment' (https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

```
$('.draggable-elements').draggable({ snap: true, containment: '.container' });
```

your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c62rsff3/1/

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. Should consider reading the documentation thorougly next time. Thank you!